# I want to update my view after updating my product quantity in angular

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular12

I have created a UI where product list is shown and there update button for updating quantity of products(both get and update method will hit my database).Now I have successfully render productlist and my update function is working too. The problem is that view not showing current data after updating my product.Page reload or 2-3 time clicks on update button needed to update my view.try to used spread operator like this this.productList=[...this.productList,res] but is shows error. Here is what i done so far

**For fetching Product**

```
productList: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
    this.getProduct();
  }

getProduct() {
    let body = {
      filterBy: 'old',
      searchKey: '',
    };
    this._productSs.getProductList(body).subscribe((res: any) => {
      res.data.forEach((element: any) => {
        Object.assign(element, { count: 0 });
      });
     
      this.productList = res;
   
    });
```

**Update Method**

```
  updateQuantity(count: any, id: any) {
    let body = {
      productId: id,
      quantity: count.toString(),
    };
    let productId = id;
    let quantity = count.toString();
  
    this._productSs.updateQuantity(quantity, productId).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.message == 'SUCCESS') {
        this.getProduct();
      }
    });
  }
```

html:
`<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of productList.data;let i=index">`

In update method I call getProduct() and get updated product value

Comment: I think you have a bad design. The this._productSs.updateQuantity should not return a message but rather an object with you products and a message. In this way you avoid another server request to return the products with getProductList method.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @JeffryHouser not getting any error just my view not updating

Comment: @Rakin Your post does say "but is shows error", which is why I asked about the error.  You should clarify the results you expect to see and the results you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some refactoring to make it work:

- change productList to an Observable and use async pipe
- use switchMap to avoid subscribe inside another subscribe

here is what you can do

```
productList$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.productList$ = this.getProduct()
}

getProduct() {
  let body = {
   filterBy: 'old',
   searchKey: '',
  };

  return this._productSs.getProductList(body)
   .pipe(
     map((res: any) => {
       res.data.forEach((element: any) => {
         Object.assign(element, { count: 0 });
       });
       return  res
    })
   )
}


updateQuantity(count: any, id: any) {
  let body = {
   productId: id,
   quantity: count.toString(),
  };
  let productId = id;
  let quantity = count.toString();

  this.productList$ =this._productSs.updateQuantity(quantity, productId).pipe(
    switchMap(res => this.getProduct())
  )
}
```

and in your tamplate

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of productList$ | async;let i=index">
```

Comment: view is updating the problem is cant access count property which i will be need to plus and minus quantity with this method: plus(number: number, index: number) { this.productList$[index].count = +this.productList$[index].count + 1; } i also try access this property by this this.productList$.subscribe((res) => { debugger; res[index].count = +res[index].count + 1; console.log('plus', res); })

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to the `Object.assign`, since it returns the updated object element after assigning the count, in your case, its updating the value but the returned object is not assigned back to the element.

Try this:

```
this._productSs.getProductList(body).subscribe((res: any) => {
      res.data.forEach((element: any) => {

        element = Object.assign(element, { count: 0 });

      });
```